# Sql Salesforce, How to know the list of email that clicked and URL

Tags: sql, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

```
select c.SubscriberKey as 'Subscriber Key', o.SubscriberKey as 'Email Address'
from _Click c
join _Open o
  on o.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID
where c.URL like '%%unsub_center_url%%'
group by c.SubscriberKey, o.SubscriberKey, c.EventDate, o.EventDate
```

I want to know the list of emails with their suscriber keys of the clients who has clicked the links for the unsuscribe option, im trying with this logic but i get no results

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.